# Push got rejected when push to heroku master, error happened when install python dependencies

Tags: python, django, reactjs, heroku

I am deploying django-react project to heroku. Push got rejected when installing python dependencies using requirements.txt. Some say this is becuasue some libraries in requirements.txt are deprecated. But I am not sure which one causes the problem and how to fix it. Thank you.

Heroku error :

```
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.3
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

My requirements.txt:

```
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==2.2.4
django-allauth==0.39.1
django-cors-headers==3.1.0
django-countries==5.4
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
djangorestframework==3.10.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
oauthlib==3.1.0
Pillow==6.1.0
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2019.2
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.3
whitenoise==4.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `setuptools==1.0` in `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

clear the buildpack using

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
```

and set the buildpack again

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```